# Power BI embedded - Publishing to Azure Workspace - Issue

Tags: powerbi-embedded

As said in many reference link, in case of embedding the power bi to a application where we are going to build a secure website, we need to embed the Power BI report by publishing the power bi report to Azure Workspace right.

In that case , for registering the power bi report in Azure AD we followed the steps specified in the below link
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-iframe/

While trying to import the .pbix file using REST API by using the POST request to api.powerbi.com, we were receiving 403 error. Hence we were not able to proceed further with the registeration/upload of PBIX file using Import API.

Also, for standalone or anonymous public embedding website we can go with Power BI Publish to Web option, using this we can get the embed code for the power bi report, which can be embedded into the web page. In case of standalone reports we can use this option to embed the power bi report on to our application, but since in our requirement we need to filter the data based on the user selection on the custom web page, we have to go with option 1 i.e. with publishing the report to AAD (Azure AD). Since we are facing authentication issue, we are unable to proceed with the process further.

Once the report is being publish we havethought of using either Power BI JavaScript or Angular JS API to pass the filter data from custom filter pane to the power BI as shown in the demo site.

Comment: Are you able to create a workspace in the workspace collection using the REST API?